# format html table as css-grid

Tags: css, html-table, css-grid

I have a wide html-table that I'd like to present for lower screen widths by styling it with pure css.

**this is the unstyled table**
[image]
*(the cells are overwide and full of content, this is just an abstract example)*

**this is the desired outcome**
[image: my goal]

Each row should be a Block with the table cells stacked on top of each other in the same order as in the html source. Then this blocks should be layouted in a grid, so that there are as many blocks next to each other as the screenwidths allows.

**Minimal Example**

```css
div {
  color: grey;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 600px;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.box {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;

  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

/*makes desired blocks*/
.wrapper td {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper td:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>

<table class="wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td class="box a">A1</td>
    <td class="box b">B1</td>
    <td class="box c">C1</td>
    <td class="box d">D1</td>
    <td class="box e">E1</td>
    <td class="box f">F1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="box a">A2</td>
    <td class="box b">B2</td>
    <td class="box c">C2</td>
    <td class="box d">D2</td>
    <td class="box e">E2</td>
    <td class="box f">F2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="box a">A3</td>
    <td class="box b">B3</td>
    <td class="box c">C3</td>
    <td class="box d">D3</td>
    <td class="box e">E3</td>
    <td class="box f">F3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="box a">A4</td>
    <td class="box b">B4</td>
    <td class="box c">C4</td>
    <td class="box d">D4</td>
    <td class="box e">E4</td>
    <td class="box f">F4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

This does give me the blocks I want. But I failed so far to arrange the  elements in a css grid.

Here is an example of what css I tried:

```
    .wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(300px, auto);
}
```

This does work on nested divs as expected ([js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u821qynz/) )

I think it brobably has something to do with tables not being allowed to be layouted as grids.

I'd like to avoid making div tables out of my data though, because semantically it is a table and I've heard that this is better for screen teaders and such.

I also tried the various  [css placement algorithms](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-css-grid-auto-placement-algorithm--cms-27563)
I looked at the [mozilla examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Auto-placement_in_CSS_Grid_Layout) and tried applying them. Also I messed around with setting [display:contents](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/07/20/why-display-contents-is-not-css-grid-layout-subgrid/) for *td* and *tr* selectevly

Comment: You can keep the table html elements. reset their display property and apply CSS Grid https://jsfiddle.net/f9q4gntp/

Comment: @ZohirSalak the ">" is doing what exactly?

Comment: `tbody{display:contents}`would work too where browser understand it ;)

Comment: @Nivatius It's for selecting direction children https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the flex model, **but do not forget that** `tbody` will be there even if not in the HTML code :

Possible example to start from or your grid fiddle attempt updated https://jsfiddle.net/218drc0t/ :

```css
div {
  color: grey;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 600px;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.box {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  font-size: 14px;
}


/*makes desired blocks*/

.wrapper td {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper td:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* DEMO UPDATE */

tbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

tr {
  margin: 5px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <table class="wrapper">
    <tr>
      <td class="box a">A1</td>
      <td class="box b">B1</td>
      <td class="box c">C1</td>
      <td class="box d">D1</td>
      <td class="box e">E1</td>
      <td class="box f">F1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="box a">A2</td>
      <td class="box b">B2</td>
      <td class="box c">C2</td>
      <td class="box d">D2</td>
      <td class="box e">E2</td>
      <td class="box f">F2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="box a">A3</td>
      <td class="box b">B3</td>
      <td class="box c">C3</td>
      <td class="box d">D3</td>
      <td class="box e">E3</td>
      <td class="box f">F3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="box a">A4</td>
      <td class="box b">B4</td>
      <td class="box c">C4</td>
      <td class="box d">D4</td>
      <td class="box e">E4</td>
      <td class="box f">F4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: ah I see so my issue was the wrong css selector due to the implied tbody, right?

Comment: Yes, this is the tricky part of it . If you do not know that browsers generates it, no way to guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem that you are running into is that for a grid layout to work, the grid *cells* need to be direct children of the grid. In a HTML table, the cells are nested inside table rows, which are nested inside the table head/body/foot.

The [`display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-box) property can come to your rescue here. It basically tells the browser to treat an element as if its children existed in its place. By applying it on the `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot` and all `tr`s of a table, you are effectively making the table cells direct children of the table, causing the grid layout to be applied properly:

```css
.wrapper > thead, .wrapper > thead > tr, .wrapper > tbody, .wrapper > tbody > tr, .wrapper > tfoot, .wrapper > tfoot > tr {
  display: contents;
}
```